# VBA Word - eliciting properties of a range-object in a text containing revision marks

Tags: vba, ms-word

A text

- containins a string of hidden text
- contains revision marks while deleted revisions are formatted as hidden.

i.e. deleted (hidden) text**visible text**

The **visible text** has been selected (not knowing that it is preceded by hidden text) and the selection is copied to a range.

```
Dim R_Visible as range
set R_Visible = selection.range
```

If I want to determine some property, i.e. the character style, VBA will elicit the style property of the whole string "deleted (hidden) text**visible text**", not only of "**visible text**". Thus, if the character style of the deleted part differs, from the character style of the visible part, VBA will return the value of `selection.ParagraphFormat.style`.

To make things more complicated I want to elicit the character style of only the 1st character of the selected text. Here are some possible approaches and their results:

a)
`Print R_Visible.characters(1).CharacterStyle` ==> Runtime error 91

b)
`Print R_Visible.characters(1).Style` ==> paragraph style

As a work-around I have written the following function:

```
Function ExactRange(Optional R_Range) As Range

Dim R_Selected As Range 

If IsMissing(R_Range) Then
    Set ExactRange = Selection.Range
Else
    'set ExactRange = R_Range.duplicate '(I haven't tested thoroughly whether that works under all circumstances)
    Set R_Selected = Selection.Range
    R_Range.Select
    Set ExactRange = Selection.Range
    R_Selected.Select 're-establishing the original selection-object 
End If

    ExactRange.SetRange Start:=ExactRange.Characters(1).End - 1, _ 
                          End:=ExactRange.Characters(Len(ExactRange)).End
End Function
```

which produces some more results:

c)
`print Mtf_ExactRange(R_Visible).style`==> character style

d) 
`print MTF_ExactRange(R_Visible).Characters(1).Style` ==> paragraph style

e)
`print MTF_ExactRange(R_Visible.characters(1)).Style`== character style

It seems to me that the behaviour is quite erratic. Can someone explain to me what is happening here and maybe point out an intended VBA-method to elicit a character style under the given circumstances without the need of a work-around function?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. After I posted the assumed solution, more questions have arisen about the whole issue and I have re-formulated the post.

Comment: OK... You also need to be careful, here, about changing the content of a question once an Answer has been posted to it. Invalidating an answer worked out and posted "in good faith" is "bad" (if the positions were reversed you wouldn't be happy, I'll bet). Just mentioning it for future reference :-)

Answer (score 1):

Selection.Style will only return one style, even if more than one has been applied. A selection can have up to 4 styles.

To find the character style of selected text, use:

```
Selection.Range.CharacterStyle
```

To get the paragraph style:

```
Selection.Range.ParagraphStyle
```

To get the table style:

```
Selection.Range.TableStyle
```

To get the list (bullets or numbering) style:

```
Selection.Range.ListStyle
```

Comment: Thank you for the useful overview. Unfortunately that doesn't solve the above stated problem, because if the selection -or a range-object is preceeded by hidden text, this hidden text seems to be included within that object, although many functions operate on the object as if the preceeding text would not be included.

Comment: It's the best I could do given the lack of clarity in your original question. As an example, you conflated hidden and deleted text, though those are 2 different things. From your new edits, I can see you're interested in hidden text. Hidden text has to retain its style characteristics, but it sounds like you would find it more convenient if it didn't.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. I am aware that hidden and deleted text are 2 different things, but in the above described circumstances, they behave the same way. Most of the time I have to deal with deleted text which is formatted as `wdDeletedTextMarkHidden`. If deleted (hidden) text is preceeding the selection or a range-object, it seems to be included and thus `selection.style` will yield an unexpected result. On the other hand, `length(selection)` and many other functions will return the expected result.